# I have trouble with the following code with different variable types and pointers for finding Bessel functions

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This assignment is one of my labs and it wants us to find the value of the 1st order Bessel function according to the input-ed user value. So long, my mindset is: first I will ask the user for input, then I use the number's rounding, the number above and the number below. After that, I perform the interpolation according to the numbers, find the error, then present everything on screen. (We must use pointers and arrays else we will not get any marks. That makes sense, how are we gonna list out every case for every rounded number from 0 to 10......)

The problem is, I seem to not get the pointers right, and the program always say that we have long int and *double mixed, even though I explicitly told the program that this is a double.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <Stdlib.h>

int y;

 int readdata(double rho[y], double Jrho[y])
{

double a, b, c, x;

FILE* fp;
fp= fopen("Bessel1.dat", "r");

for (y=0; y<=10; y++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf", &rho[y], &Jrho[y]);
    }

}

double Lagrange2nd(int y, double rho[y], double Jrho[y], double x)
{

double a, b, c;

double output;

a=(x-rho[(y+1)])*((x-rho[y])*Jrho[((y-1))]+(rho[((y-1))]-
```

x)*Jrho[y])/(rho[((y-1))]-rho[y]);

```
b=(((rho[(y-1)]-x)*((x-rho[(y+1)])*Jrho[y]+(rho[y]-
```

x)*Jrho[(y+1)]))/(rho[y]-rho[(y+1)]));

```
output = c = (a+b)/(rho[(y-1)]-rho[(y+1)]);

return output;
}

double errx(int y, double rho[y], double Jrho[y], double x)
{
double a, b, c;

double output;

output= (abs(c-(Jrho[(y-1)]*(x-rho[y])+Jrho[y]*(rho[(y-1)]-x)))+abs(c- 
(Jrho[y]*(x-rho[(y+1)])+Jrho[(y+1)]*(rho[y]-x))))/2;

return output;

}

int main()
{
double x, Jrho[y], rho[y];

printf("x=");
scanf("%lf", &x);
y=round(x);

Lagrange2nd(&rho[y], &x, &Jrho[y], y);

errx(&Jrho[y], &x, &rho[y], y);

printf("%d, %d", Lagrange2nd, errx);

return(0);
}
```

I know this is messy, but I did not know any programming until 2 months ago, yet we now have to do this......gee, I am not very good at this, am I?

Comment: Is your lab assignment really requiring to do it in C? There are better suited languages for this.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to use Python too, but I have not learned it, as I have said, I knew 0 programming until I took the course 2 months ago. It was basic binary, then the basic programming, the for loop, the while loop, the do loop, then it is pointers and arrays. The rest of the labs are pretty simple, but this lab is painstakingly hard. (You will not believe how easy it is to program the trapezoidal rule!)

Comment: Then your language choice for this assignment is not very appropriate. You will learn python by the time you make it work in C :) But I would go with Matlab/Octave instead.

Comment: Start by breaking the equation down in several steps, use temporary variables etc.

Comment: `abs()` is for integers, Use `fabs()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What compiler do you use ? with gcc you will get MANY warnings. In particular, you have few functions that declare to return void, but return an int.

Looks like you compiler does treat 'void' as 'int' - which will cause lot of precision issue. If you have turned of warning - consider re-enabling them, or use better compiler :-)

```
void errx(double* rho[y], double* Jrho[y], double* x)
{
...
double output;

output= (abs(c-(Jrho[(y-1)]*(x-rho[y])+Jrho[y]*(rho[(y-1)]-x)))+abs(c-(Jrho[y]*(x- 
rho[(y+1)])+Jrho[(y+1)]*(rho[y]-x))))/2;

return output;
}
```

Style note: consider combing declaration and assignment in one statement. It will reduce many possible errors, and will get you better grade!

```
double output = (abs(c-(Jrho[(y-1)]*(x-rho[y])+Jrho[y]*(rho[(y-1)]-x)))+abs(c-(Jrho[y]*(x-rho[(y+1)])+Jrho[(y+1)]*(rho[y]-x))))/2;
```

Comment: Oh, so there are other compilers! My professor told us to use GCC, so we just installed it to our laptops. As for enabling errors, I'll see about it. Another problem is that when your advice helps, I still do not understand how to make my program work. I mean, it said that there are long int and *double. But the problem is, y is a integer, but the arrays rho[y] and Jrho[y] are not, however, I somehow make the computer mix them both, and I don't know why. I have been thinking on this for 2 weeks already lol. I guess I really suck at this XD

Comment: @hyacinthchan There code does not compile on GCC. Suggest you will get it to compile first, fix the return types, and then see what do you get.

Comment: Ok, so I did a few mends and I found out the current issue is the main calling program. Now, what I currently encounter is that there are not enough arguments for the Lagrange2nd and Error functions. Why is that so? I included everything the computer needed to know. Also, it said that the rho[y] and Jrho[y] inside line 59 and 61 are neither pointer, not array, nor vector. While obviously I am trying to call a pointer and an array at the same time.

Comment: Please update POST with current code. Hard to tell what problem you have on code that we do not see.

Comment: And also note that Lagrange2nd takes 4 arguments, but you are passing on 3 (in main), what happens to X ?

Comment: Oh! I do not have much experience here, so, sorry. :) Updated btw.

Comment: OK, now this is the final updated version. The only problem remaining is it saying that "y" in line 61 and 59 are not compatible. They expected double, but argument is of type int*. I thought I said everything is int! The calling program should have no problem reading my line. :/

Comment: Lagrange2nd is expecting double, you are trying to pass int *. Not going to work.

Comment: Ok, now the program successfully compiles, but when I run it it gave me a segmentation error. I know you have been very patient to me, and I sincerely thank you for it. But a segmentation error is not easy to spot (happened a few times in my homework, that case was I was trying to tell the computer to access something outside the array limit......). So it is OK if you just want to ditch me away......checking programs is painstakingly hard. :P Anyways, thank you. :)

Comment: You can usually get much more insight using a debugger. When you compile (gcc ...), use 'gcc -g ...'. Then run the program with gdb: 'gdb myprog ; run ... ; where`. This will give you the line number the crashed

Comment: If the program compiles, and if you do are unable to use gdb, please post the Bessel1.dat file, and your input, so that it is possible to replicate. Without this information, it's too much guess work